# Mysql update query is it possible to have a case statement and select statement under set

Tags: mysql

I'm having trouble with the `SET` of an update query. I would like to query another table and if that table is null then but a new time in. here is the code but it returns nothing. not getting any errors.

```
SET 
sched.Start= case when  (SELECT employee from sched where Day=Days and shift='Pm' and store = Stores and job='Driver') is null then '2018-01-01 16:00:00' else '2018-01-01 17:00:00' end
```

if I run the select in a separate query it works?

```
select  case when (SELECT employee from sched where Day='Thu' and shift='Pm' and store = 2284 and job='Pm Bread') is null then '2018-01-01 16:00:00' else '2018-01-01 17:00:00' end
```

Comment: That's not even a valid `UPDATE` clause.  Where's your `UPDATE`??? I don't see it.  `UPDATE` clause begins with the word `UPDATE`, not `SET`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are missing the Update  from your code above

UPDATE  table_reference
    SET assignment_list
    [WHERE where_condition]
    [ORDER BY ...]
    [LIMIT row_count]

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/update.html